# Create a lookup column using powershell. How i can define the related Lookup list

Tags: development, powershell, lookup-column

I am working on-premise SharePoint server 2016. and i want to create a new site column of type Lookup. the column display name will be "Department". so when i try to create the column using the UI i got an error that the Department column already exists.
so i want to create the column using power-shell, so i can have its Display  name = Department. Now i tried this script:-

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://***1/"
$web = $site.RootWeb


#Assign fieldXML variable with XML string for site column
$fieldXML = '<Field Type="Lookup"
Name="MyDepartment"
Description=""
DisplayName="Department"
StaticName="MyDepartment"
Group="custom columns"
Hidden="FALSE"
Required="TRUE"
Sealed="FALSE"
ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"
ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
ShowInListSettings="TRUE"
ShowInNewForm="TRUE">
</Field>'

#Output XML to console
write-host $fieldXML

#Create site column from XML string
$web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXML)
```

which created a lookup column. but when i edit it using the UI i was not able to select the lookup list. so seems i need to define this using powershell .. so can anyone advice on this please? how i can define the lookup list and its related fields using powershell for my new lookup column??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as below xml:

**Option 1**

```
<Field Type="Lookup" 
    ID="{AD45AC76-D1E2-46C8-A047-E8C43C10205C}" 
    Name="MyDepartment" 
    StaticName="MyDepartment" 
    DisplayName="Department" 
    Required="FALSE" 
    List="Lists/TestList" 
    ShowField="Title"   
    Group="custom Columns" />
```

You need to specify the `List` and `ShowField`.

List == the destination list from which you want to get data

ShowField == the destination list column which will be "looked up".

In case it's a multi-valued lookup, you also need to specify `Mult=TRUE`.

**Option 2**

You can also add it as below:

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://***/"
$web = $site.RootWeb
$lookupList = $web.Lists["Testlist"]  
$web.Fields.AddLookup("MyDepartment", $lookupList.ID,$false);
$field = $web.Fields["MyDepartment"]
$field.LookupField = $lookupList.Fields["Title"]
$field.Title = "Department"
$field.Update()
```

[SPFieldCollection.AddLookup method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms436747.aspx)

Comment: but why u are specifying the Id of column ??? I usually create site columns using power shell without having to specify the Id

Comment: yes no need to specify it. Its optional. You can remove that in your code.

Comment: now i tried defining the xml as you mentioned ,, but the lookup list will be empty...

Comment: now i tried defining the xml as you mentioned ,, now the lookup column will be created but the lookup list (Get information from) for the lookup field will be empty...

Comment: In the list option , please try it as List="Testlist"  or List="guid of destination list" instead of List="Lists/Testlist" ?

Comment: Have also added another option. Can you check that out as well ?

Comment: your second appraoch has raised the following exception :- At line:1 char:41
+ $web.Fields.AddLookup("MyDepartment",lookupList.ID, false);
+                                         ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:41
+ $web.Fields.AddLookup("MyDepartment",lookupList.ID, false);

Comment: so i think i need to add 2 $ signs as follow:- $web.Fields.AddLookup("MyDepartment", $lookupList.ID, $false); instead of $web.Fields.AddLookup("MyDepartment", lookupList.ID, false); ???

Comment: yes correct, my bad missed the `$` sign. It should  be`$web.Fields.AddLookup("MyDepartment", $lookupList.ID, false);`, have modified the answer

Comment: so do you have any idea why my original appraoch fail to connect the lookup column with the lookup list? and using your second appraoch (Option-2) can i control the ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" options?? as i have this facility using XML??

Comment: and also i need to add $ sign for the false .. is this correct?

Comment: yes again my bad, its $false. Yes, you can control it as `$field.ShowInNewForm = $true` ,  `$field.ShowInEditForm = $true` etc .  Am not sure about the first approach, did you try with list guid or list title ?

Comment: i actually proceed with ur second appraoch... since the end result should be the same a lookup column will be created..